# jetpack compose, I want two gaps to fill the remaining space, and the ratio is one to two

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

i have column, i want SpacerA height = SpacerC height, and SpacerB height = SpacerA height / 2

```
column {
    SpacerA
    Xxx()
    SpaceB
    Xxx("")
    SpacerC
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(2f))
    Text("First")
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
    Text("Second")
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(2f))
}
```

[image]